# Why has this error happened?

Tags: apex, visualforce, error-messages, custom-controller

Error:

> Duplicate id in list: 0012800000pArJzAAK Error is in expression
>   '{!Savemeth}' in component  in page
>   accounteditcontrollerpage: Class.AccountEditController.Savemeth: line
>   55, column 1

My controller:

```
public class AccountEditController {

    public String closePopup { get; set; }

    accountwrapper1 makeEdit;
    List<accountwrapper1> listAccount = new List<accountwrapper1>();
    List<Account> selectableAccount = new List<Account>();
    List<Account> selectableAccount2 = new List<Account>();
    //public Boolean showPanel {get; set;}
    public Boolean showPopup { get; set; }

   public AccountEditController() {
          showPopup = False;
         //showPanel = False;
   }

    public List<accountwrapper1> getAccounts() {
        if(listAccount == Null){
            for(Account a: [SELECT Id, Name, BillingCountry, Phone FROM Account])
            listAccount.add(new accountwrapper1(a));
            return listAccount; }
        else{
            listAccount.clear();
            for(Account a: [SELECT Id, Name, BillingCountry, Phone FROM Account])
            listAccount.add(new accountwrapper1(a));
            return listAccount;            
            }           
    }

     public PageReference showToPopup() {
   // public PageReference showToPanel() {
        showPopUp = True;
        //showPanel  = True;
         selectableAccount.clear();
        for(accountwrapper1 accwrapper : listAccount)
        if(accwrapper.selected == True)
        selectableAccount.add(accwrapper.acc);
        system.debug(selectableAccount);
        return Null;

    }

    public string BillingCountry {
        get; 
        set;
    }


    public PageReference Savemeth() {
        for(account acc :selectableAccount ) {
                acc.BillingCountry = BillingCountry;
                  selectableAccount2.add(acc);

        }    
    update selectableAccount2;
    showPopup = False;
    return Null;

    }

    public PageReference cancelmeth() {        
        return Null;
    }

    public PageReference closePopup() {
       // showPopup.clear();
        showPopup = False;   
        return Null;
    }

    public PageReference GetSelectedAccounts()
    {
       if(selectableAccount.size()>0) {
        system.debug(selectableAccount.size());
        system.debug(selectableAccount);
       return Null;
        }
        else
        return Null;
    } 


     public class accountwrapper1
    {             
        public Account acc{get; set;}      
        public Boolean selected {get; set;}
        public accountwrapper1(Account a)
        {
            acc = a;
            selected = False;
        }
    }
}
```

My Page:

```
<apex:page controller="AccountEditController" applyHtmlTag="true">
    <style type="text/css">
    .PopupBackground{
        background-color:pink;
        opacity: 0.8;
        filter: alpha(opacity = 20);
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 200%;
        top: -100px;
        left: 10px;
        z-index: 9998;
    }
    .AccountEdit{
        background-color: white;
        border-width: 8px;
        border-style: solid;
        z-index: 9999;
        left: 20%;
        padding:10px;
        position: absolute;
        width: 300px;
        margin-left: 75px;
        top:300px;
    }
    </style>
        <apex:form >
            <apex:pageBlock Title="List of Accounts" >

                   <apex:pageBlockButtons location="top">
                        <apex:commandButton value="Get selected Records" action="{!showToPopup}" rerender="Output" id="button"/>
                        <apex:commandButton value="cancelPopup" action="{!closePopup}" rendered="output"/>
                      <!-- <apex:commandButton value="Get selected Records" action="{!showToPanel}" rerender="Output" id="button"/>---->

                   </apex:pageBlockButtons>

                 <!-- {!showPanel}---->
                      <apex:outputPanel id="Output">
                          <apex:outputPanel styleClass="PopupBackground" layout="black" rendered="{!showPopup}">
                              <apex:outputPanel styleClass="AccountEdit" layout="black" rendered="{!showPopup}">
                         <!---  <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!showPanel}">----->
                           <!---{!showPanel}---------->
                               <apex:outputLabel value="BillingCountry: "></apex:outputLabel>
                               <apex:inputText id="BillingCountry" value="{!BillingCountry}" size="40" style="height:13px;font-size:11px;"/><br />                   
                               <apex:commandButton value="save" action="{!Savemeth}" reRender="Initialtable,Output"/>
                              <!-- <apex:commandButton value="cancel" action="{!cancelmeth}"/>---->
                               <apex:commandButton value="cancelPopup" action="{!closePopup}"/>
                                </apex:outputPanel>
                            </apex:outputPanel>                   
                        </apex:outputPanel>  
                 <!--   <apex:commandButton value="cancelPopup" action="{!closePopup}"/>--->
                   <apex:pageBlockSection Title="List of Available Accounts" columns="1" collapsible="true">
                            <apex:pageblockTable value="{!accounts}" var="a" id="Initialtable">

                                <apex:column headerValue="Select" width="60">
                                    <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!a.Selected}" id="checkedone" />
                                </apex:column>

                                <apex:column headervalue="Account Name" value="{!a.acc.Name}" width="200"/>
                                <apex:column headervalue="Phone" value="{!a.acc.Phone}" width="300"/>
                                <apex:column headervalue="Billing Country" value="{!a.acc.BillingCountry}" width="300"/>

                            </apex:pageblocktable>
                   </apex:pageBlockSection>

            </apex:pageblock>
        </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: no need to add this line `selectableAccount2.add(acc);` . just remove it

Comment: @Ratan Sorry sir If remove this line my save method not updated to the selectableAccount2 so what's result means even Ientered the text box any country name  in the model popup box it's not updated in the selectable account.

Comment: ahh my mistake.. two variable is there selectableAccount2 and selectableAccount. SO in your selectableAccount2 list contains same record 2 times that's you are getting this error.

Comment: @Ratan Sir, I struggle to understand your answer in my code can please give the changes I will try  to understand clearly sir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is selectableAccount2 contains duplicate records.

you can solve this using a map variable

```
public PageReference Savemeth() 
{
    map<Id, Account> mapAccountForUpdate = new map<Id, Account>();
    for(account acc :selectableAccount ) 
    {
        acc.BillingCountry = BillingCountry;
        mapAccountForUpdate.put(acc.Id, acc);
    }    
    update mapAccountForUpdate.values();
    showPopup = False;
    return Null;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for helping to clear understand sir!!!

Comment: @MohanRaj problem was. your list that defined above that contains same record two times thats why it was throwing the duplicate id error